# Linear programming on graph

Tags: graph-theory, optimization, algorithms, linear-programming

Given connected undirected graph with n<2e3 nodes and m<1e5 vertices. For each road we know it's length l_i and cost c_i.

Find the minimum F value (see below).

For path_j from vertice 1 to n we calculate F as the total sum of l_i * c_i / t_i for each of its edges (where the t_i - time spent to travel its i'th road), and t_1 + ... + t_k <= T. T is given. k here is the number of edges of path.

My thoughts:

1. Lets assign w_i as l_i * c_i for each edge
2. Sort every edge by w_i and try to find the path with minimal total w_i of each edge on it.

But I think that is not optimal solution (in sense of answer).

Another solution - brute-force:

1. Find all possible paths from 1 to n.
2. For each path and each of its edge try to assign t's values s.t. sum w_i / t_i is minimized and sum t_i <= T

This solution is too sklow, considering that number of different paths from 1 to n is very big.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a fixed path with weights $w_1, w_2, \dots, w_k$, the sum $\frac{w_1}{t_1} + \frac{w_2}{t_2} + \dots + \frac{w_k}{t_k}$ subject to $t_1 + t_2 + \dots + t_k \le T$ is minimized when $t_i = \frac{T \sqrt{w_i}}{\sqrt{w_1} + \sqrt{w_2} + \dots + \sqrt{w_k}}$: essentially, when $t_i \propto \sqrt{w_i}$, with the scaling factor being whatever we need for the sum to equal $T$. Then the sum is equal to $(\sqrt{w_1} + \sqrt{w_2} + \dots + \sqrt{w_k})^2/T$. This is a direct consequence of [Titu's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sedrakyan%27s_inequality).

Therefore to find the best path, you should find the shortest path with respect to the weights $\sqrt{w_i}$.